# At. React + TypeScript, How can I Directly know about "event object's type" by type-inference?

Tags: typescript, types, visual-studio-code, type-inference, react-typescript

(*VSCode*)

When I Disunite the event from jsx code. (at. class Component)

Like This⬇

```
 handleSubmit = e => { ...}


render(){
return (
  <>
    <form onSubmit={this.handelSubmit}>
      <input
        ref={this.onRefInput}
        type='number'
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
      <button>입력!</button>
    </form>
  </>
);}
```

Usually When others raise the cursor on the "onSubmit"

tsc  say

> "React.DOMAttributes< HTMLFormElement >onSubmit?***:(event:
> React.FormEvent< HTMLFormElement >)=> void) | undefined*** "

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrcug.png)

So, We can directly know about event object's type! (event: React.FormEvent< HTMLFormElement >)

✅ Problem is that my code doesn't announces as above.

My tsc  say

> " React.DOMAttributes< HTMLFormElement >.onSubmit?:
> ***React.FormEventHandler< HTMLFormElement > | undefined***"

So, ***I can't directly know about event object's type!***

I know that there are many other ways to know about event object's type.

But I want to **directly know about event object's type**! by Type inference.

How can I **directly know about event object's type**! by Type inference?

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a type to either to the function itself or to the arguments of the function, which is the event.

---

```
React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>
```

This is the type for the function.  If you use it like this:

```
handleSubmit: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = e => {
}
```

Then the type for the variable `e` will be inferred as `React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` automatically.  So you don't actually need to know the event type because you can apply a type to the function itself and get the correct type.

---

Or you can assign the type to the event argument `e`.

```
handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
}
```

Now the type for the `handleSubmit` property is inferred as `(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void`.

Comment: While this is true, it doesn't answer the question of why OPs VSCode tooltip doesn't work the way it is usually presented in various answers/tutorials/videos/etc

Answer (score 0):

In advance, sorry for that This answer is not a complete solution

I had the same problem, and I searched a lot, and try to change all settings.json about typescript.inlayHints.
unfortunately, nothing works

So I go to the implementation of onSubmit
[image]

If you hover over onSubmit with command key (maybe ctrl key another OS)
you can go to index.d.ts
then you can see

```
        onSubmit?: FormEventHandler<T> | undefined;
```

so I changed it as

```
        onSubmit?: (event: FormEvent<T>) => void | undefined;
```

and now I can get what you want
[image]

I think, the new version of node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts results in like the first image.

Using Eventhandler type is also a good solution, If you hover over `e` parameter, you can see the Event Object

[image]